# Maintain color from script output for later viewing

Tags: colors, console, output

I want to save the output from a script so I can view it later. However, when I save the output to a file (`script > some/file`) and view it later, there's no color, even though `script` originally outputs in several colors to make the output easier to read.

It makes sense that the color isn't saved since the resulting file is just plain text, but is there any way I can take any given script, and reproduce the output later with the same styling without invoking the script again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some programs (including whatever you put in your *script*) detect whether the output is a terminal or a file, and turn off colors for that case.  If you run your *script* using the *program* **`script`**, that avoids this problem, by capturing all of the characters into a file named **`typescript`**, e.g.,

**`script`** **`-c`** *script*

(where the latter is of course, your *script*) and later

```
cat typescript
```

Depending on the system, the **`script`** program may use different arguments.  The first (defaulting to **`typescript`**) is where the **`script`** program writes its output:

- the one on Debian/Ubuntu/etc is in a package named "bsdutils", and the *command* must be given using a **`-c`** option, e.g, "**`script`** **`-c`** *script*".
- on a ***BSD*** system, there is no **`-c`** option, and the command can be given be given as parameters after the *file*, e.g,. "**`script`** **`typescript`** *script*".

Though supported on (probably) every POSIX system, **`script`** is not part of [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Comment: On my distribution of Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) the syntax was a little different. I could accomplish this with `echo "scriptName ; exit" | script test` where "test" is the name of the file to store the output, and "scriptName" is the name of the script I want to store the output for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `less -R <filename>.<fileformat>` command to open your output file. It should display the colors...

Just in case here is an example of colored echo:
`RED='\033[0;31m'`
`NC='\033[0m' # No Color`
`printf "I ${RED}love${NC} Stack Overflow\n"`

Also, you can use html file as output file and then open it in your browser:
`echo "<div style='color:$COLOR;'>$SOMEVARIABLE</div><br>" > output.html`
(the color should be in HEX format, for example `#040404`)